# Python function ignoring FOR loop

Tags: python

The following script Ignores the FOR LOOP and finishes without error, I want to know why.

I tried adding print() messages to figure out where the error is happening, everything I write before the FOR loop works fine, but anything after gets ignored.

```
import requests


def search_results(search_term):

    variable_name = search_term.replace(' ','20%')

    
    variable_name_1 = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q=" + str(variable_name) + "&sort=price_asc"

    r = requests.get(str(variable_name_1))
    a  = r.json()

    print("I'm working fine up until here")

    for result in a['results']:
    

        title_0 = result['title']
        price_0 = result['price']
        url_0 = result['permalink']
        listing_type = result['listing_type_id']
        shipping  =  result['shipping']['free_shipping']


        print("why am i ignoring this???")



        with open("query2.txt", 'a+') as f:
            f.write((url_0)+";"+str(title_0)+";"+listing_type+";"+str(shipping)+';'+str(price_0))
            f.write("\n")
        

    
search_term = "gt 710"

search_results(search_term)
```

Comment: It is likely that `a["results"]` is empty, so there's nothing to loop.

Comment: I tried running the same code but out of the function and it works fine, that's why im puzzled.

Comment: Have you tried `print(a['results'])` just before the `for` loop? I'd think that would be the first step in tracking down the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. Just replace this:

```py
variable_name = search_term.replace(' ','20%')
```

with this:

```py
variable_name = search_term.replace(' ', '%20')
```

And everything would work fine.